# Can we represent a square using a single matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

My objective is to represent a unit square using a single matrix.
The four corners of the unit square are represented by column vectors as follows,

$\left[\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right],\left[\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right],\left[\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right],\left[\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right]$

when we write these points in a single matrix, it becomes $2 X 4$ matrix and we cannot multiply it with the standard matrix which is $2 X 2$, but when written as $\left[\begin{matrix} 0&0 \\ 1&0\\ 1&1\\0&1 \end{matrix}\right] $, it becomes $4 X 2 $ matrix which we can multiply with standard matrix of $2 X 2$ and produces the desired result.

I find it counter-intuitive as points are represented by column vectors.

***Question:*** Is it valid to say that by writing a  4 X 2  matrix I am representing a square by mentioning the four corners of it ?

Comment: What is a standard matrix?

Comment: 1st row:1,0, second row 0,-1

Comment: this particular standard matrix reflects the unit square though horizontal axis

Answer (score 4):

You should transpose this matrix:

$$C=\left[\begin{matrix} 0&1&1&0 \\ 0&0&1&1 \end{matrix}\right]$$

With this presentation, any linear operation $L$ on $C$ will be $C'$ given by $L \times C=:C'$; for example,

1) The orthogonal reflection with respect to the $x$ axis (leaving $x$ axis invariant) is given by:

$$\underbrace{\left[\begin{matrix} 1& \ \ 0 \\ 0&-1\end{matrix}\right]}_L\underbrace{\left[\begin{matrix} 0&1&1&0 \\ 0&0&1&1 \end{matrix}\right]}_C=\underbrace{\left[\begin{matrix} 0&1& \ \ 1& \ \ 0 \\ 0&0&-1&-1 \end{matrix}\right]}_{C'}.$$

2) The $\pi/2$ rotation around $O$ is given by:

$$\left[\begin{matrix} 0&-1 \\ 1& \ \ 0\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix} 0&1&1&0 \\ 0&0&1&1 \end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix} 0&0& -1& -1 \\ 0&1& \ \ 1& \ \ 0 \end{matrix}\right].$$

Comment: thanx, you mean x axis

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you are right $x$ axis.

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ might be understood to represent

the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:x=t\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}+s\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix},0\leq t,s\leq 1\}$, the square, and more genearlly

$\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{pmatrix}$ might be understood to represent the parallelogram

$\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:x=t\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}\\a_{21}\end{pmatrix}+s\begin{pmatrix}a_{12}\\a_{22}\end{pmatrix}0\leq t,s\leq 1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can't multiply
$$X = \begin{bmatrix}0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}$$
by a $2\times2$ matrix $A$ on the right, but you can on the *left*. In fact,
if $x_1, \dots, x_k$ are $n\times 1$ vectors, $A$ is any $n\times n$ matrix, and
$$X = \begin{bmatrix}x_1&\dots&x_k\end{bmatrix},$$
then
$$AX = \begin{bmatrix}Ax_1&\dots&Ax_k\end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus we can apply a linear operator to an entire collection of points (*any* finite collection from the same finite dimensional vector space) "simultaneously" via matrix multiplication.